# Bootstrap-select Multi-select rendered wrongly

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

What I have:

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select className="selectpicker" multiple title="Choose one of the following...">
        <option>OK</option>
        <option>PENDING</option>
        <option>NEW</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

PROBLEM:

Values (OK, PENDING, NEW) are displayed separately in another scrolled field. Whereas the drop down select field is displayed as separate field beside it. The drop down select field has no value inside. Screenshot attached.

[image: Screenshot]

What I wanted is this kind of dropdown: (Taken from [Bootstrap-select documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/))

[image]

The technology stack of my project:

- Bootstrap-select 1.13.1
- .Net
- Bootstrap 3.x
- ReactJs

Could this be compatibility issue?

**EDIT**

I'v given up. I had to choose to use bootstrap-multiselect instead. It is much less confusing. Recommend it!

Answer (score 3):

Please check this:
I have used the https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ and it works great.

```
import React from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

export default class SelectComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: '',
  }
  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Selected: ${selectedOption.label}`);
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        name="form-field-name"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        multi
        options={[
          { value: 'one', label: 'One' },
          { value: 'two', label: 'Two' },
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19798251)

Comment: @fhdrsdg : I am not sure why you had to downvote because I had given the exact answer the user had asked.

Comment: You're assuming I downvoted, which I didn't. As the comment says, you haven't posted the solution. What you posted is directions to where someone may find the answer. If that link breaks, your answer becomes useless. Also read [this answer in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/276063)

Comment: :) thanks for the tip and thank you for correcting me.. noted. The reason I mentioned the npm package was, I used it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for??

```
<div className="col-md-2">
    <label>Status</label>
    <select className="selectpicker">
        <option selected="selected">Choose one of the following</option>
        <option>OK</option>
        <option>PENDING</option>
        <option>NEW</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. This is not what I wanted.